# Why has many through cant associate through has one or many?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

So, if i have this models

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments
end

class Page < ActiverRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
  has_many :comments, through: :post
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
end
```

It would raise `ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughCantAssociateThroughHasOneOrManyReflection` if i run:

```
$ irb> page = Page.new
$ irb> page.comments.build
$ irb> page.save
```

Why rails would raise `ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughCantAssociateThroughHasOneOrManyReflection`

Why is it impossible to make such thing as `post_id` is available via `page` model.

PS.
this sample is related to https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/11164

Comment: In class `Comment` add `belongs_to :page`

Comment: @steveklein `belongs_to :page` require `page_id` to be available on the `comments` table.

Comment: belongs_to :page, in the Post model.

Comment: @FunTimeFreddie sorry my bad. I fixed the code. it is `belongs_to :post` instead of `has_many :posts` .It was a remake of the one of my project in a simpler form.

Comment: `has_many :comments, through: :posts` - you do not have `posts` association, change it to `:post`